# Google Analytics Measurement Id as Environment Variable

Tags: javascript, django, google-analytics

I just started using Google Analytics and I have my code in my base html file for a Django web app.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->        
<script nonce="{{ CSP_NONCE }}" async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXX"></script>
<script nonce="{{ CSP_NONCE }}">
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag("config","G-XXXXXXXXX");
</script>
<!-- end GA -->
```

My question is, for the measurement id (G-XXXXXXXXX) is this something that needs to be a secret? I keep all my keys, etc in the env file and thought I could do the same with this id but I keep running into errors. I tried {% 'GOOGLE_ID' %} but that didn't work.

Is there a good way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Tag Measurement ID will be rendered plainly to html code and will be visible publicly when someone views the website source code. Hence, it doesn't have to be a secret.

However, if you're looking to use it across several places in your app or you have different ID for diffrent pages/use cases, it might be helpful to store it in a variable so you can use the variable easily and apply it without typos.